# Javascript code displays undefined when program is run

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, prototype

My program has to use the string prototype property even though it is unnecessary. Whenever the submit button is clicked, it results in a bunch of undefined. 
Within the show_alphabet function I have a variable named “str”, a string of the letters of the alphabet in uppercase.

Within the show_alphabet function, I have the code for using the prototype property of the String object to add a method named “sendArray” and assign this (sendArray) a function which returns the split() method. The split() method will split the alphabet string.

I am trying to display the alphabet letters in the “str” as an array with period colon followed by each letter and placing each letter on a separate line. 
For example:
A:
B:
C:
…

Although I realize that the string prototype property does not have to be used, the guidelines for my assignment say they must be used. Here are the relevant parts of my code.

```
<form>
<button type = "button" onclick = show_alphabet()>submit</button>
</form>
<script type "text/javascript">
function show_alphabet() {
var str = new String("ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ");
String.prototype.sendArray = function() {
    return this.split("");
}
var arr = str.sendArray 
for (i = 0; i<str.length- 1; i++) {
    str.split(":<br />");
    document.write(arr[i]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This: `var arr = str.sendArray`

Should be: `var arr = str.sendArray()`

Otherwise you are assigning the function to `arr` and not the function result.

Example:

```js
var str = new String("ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ");
String.prototype.sendArray = function() {
    return this.split("");
}
var arr = str.sendArray(); 
var arrLength = arr.length; // length of the array should be calculated before the loop, or it will be calculated on every interaction.
for (i = 0; i<arrLength; i++) {
    arr[i]+=":<br />"
    console.log(arr[i]);
}
```

Comment: Yes, but now, it displays only the str variable, and the for loop hasn't run

Comment: Run the code that I added and point out what does not meet your requirements.

Comment: I updated a few things, like the length of the array should be calculated before the loop, or it will be calculated on every interaction.

Comment: @AB also, if this solution worked for you, consider choosing it as the right answer.

Answer (score 0):

Change the part of your code

```
var arr = str.sendArray
```

to

```
var arr = str.sendArray();
```

so that you are actually assigning the returned value of a function call, no the function itself.